# Styles defined under another path fails to work in \node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I make the following code to test the use of `\node` in `tikz`. I find that using styles defined under another path(/a in this example) will cause problems - please see the MWE for details. Anyone can help me with the cause and how to handle it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/a/.search also={/tikz},
  /a/.cd,
  myshape/.style={fill=red,circle},
  size/.style={minimum size=#1*0.5cm},
  size/.default=1
}

% example No.1:
\tikz\node[fill=red,circle]{AAA}; %The option "circle" can be used dirctly in "\node".

% example No.2:
% Contrasted with example No.1, why can "circle" not be used in myshape/.style which leads to unsuccessful compile?
% \tikz[/tikz/.search also={/a}]\node[myshape]{AAA}; 

% example No.3:
% Why does the "size=3" not work?
\tikz[/tikz/.search also={/a}]\node[fill=red,size=3]{AAA}; 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking why `circle` works. The answer to this is actually a bit delicate and contained in the following code block from `tikz.code.tex`:

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.unknown/.code=%
  % Is it a pgf key?
  \let\tikz@key\pgfkeyscurrentname%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/\tikz@key/.try={#1}}%
  \ifpgfkeyssuccess%
  \else%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter!\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
      % this is a color!
      \expandafter\tikz@addoption\expandafter{\expandafter\tikz@compat@color@set\expandafter{\tikz@key}}%
      \edef\tikz@textcolor{\tikz@key}%
    \else%
      \pgfutil@doifcolorelse{\tikz@key}
      {%
        \expandafter\tikz@addoption\expandafter{\expandafter\tikz@compat@color@set\expandafter{\tikz@key}}%
        \edef\tikz@textcolor{\tikz@key}%
      }%
      {%
        % Ok, second chance: This might be an arrow specification:
        \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter-\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@%
          % Ah, an arrow spec!
          \expandafter\tikz@processarrows\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \else%
          % Ok, third chance: A shape!
          \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@s@\tikz@key\endcsname\relax%
            \pgfkeys{/errors/unknown key/.expand
              once=\expandafter{\expandafter/\expandafter t\expandafter i\expandafter k\expandafter z\expandafter/\tikz@key}{#1}}%
          \else%
            \edef\tikz@shape{\tikz@key}%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}%
```

As you can see, Ti*k*Z tries out all sorts of things. This is convenient for users because they can say `circle` instead of `shape=circle` and `red` instead of `color=red`.

You could make your code work with `/.try`. However, I do not recommend this. Rather, I recommend just giving Ti*k*Z the missing pieces of information, i.e. to say `shape=circle` instead of `circle` and `/pgf/minimum size` instead of `minimum size`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/a/.search also={/tikz},
  /a/.cd,
  myshape/.style={fill=red,shape=circle},
  size/.style={/pgf/minimum size=#1*0.5cm},
  size/.default=1
}

% example No.1:
\tikz\node[fill=red,circle]{AAA}; %The option "circle" can be used dirctly in "\node".

% example No.2:
% Contrasted with example No.1, why can "circle" not be used in myshape/.style which leads to unsuccessful compile?
\tikz[/tikz/.search also={/a}]\node[myshape]{AAA}; 

% example No.3:
% Why does the "size=3" not work?
\tikz[/tikz/.search also={/a}]\node[fill=red,size=3]{AAA}; 

\end{document}
```

The reason why I am recommending this is that if you overdo the `/.try` and so on thingies, it becomes less and less clear which key has priority.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail solutions!!!